Syncing "Available Repositories" on Satellite Server 6.14
I have a Satellite Server (we'll call this 'client') running 6.14 that is connected to another Satellite Server (we'll call this one 'main').  My 'client' Satellite Server is dependent on the other 'main' Satellite Server for new content.  I have a 2nd Satellite Server that is disconnected (not really a concern with this problem).  So I know how to export data from my 'client' Satellite Server to my disconnected Satellite Server.  But, I noticed a repository that is newly available on my 'client' Satellite Server but I don't see it in the Content->Red Hat Repositories so I can add it to my content view to export to my disconnected server.
Am I suppose to perform some sync with my 'client' Satellite Server to the 'main' Satellite Server?  And I'm not talking about syncing the repository content, I'm talking about seeing any  new available repositories that I can add to my content view.
Or is this something managed by the manifest file?
